# this is a program to find prime numbers from 2 to 100 in C

Tags: c

I am unable to understand how is it working. Can somebody explain me this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    /* local variable definition */
    int i, j;

    for(i = 2; i<100; i++) {
        for(j = 2; j <= (i/j); j++) {
            if(!(i%j)) break; // if factor found, not prime
        }
        if(j > (i/j)) printf("%d is prime", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `j <= (i/j)` is an unnecessarily obfuscated and inefficient way of writing `j * j <= i`. If you still don't understand, get yourself a better book.

Comment: Hopefully some extra braces will help to understand.

Comment: For all its attempts at looking clever this algorithm is terrible.

Comment: `j <= (i/j)` is not quite equivalent to `j*j <= i` since integer division rounds toward zero.

Comment: `/* local variable definition */` ranks right up there with `i = i + 1; // increment i` in terms of the "most useless comment" award :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is looping over all integers from `2` to `99`, holding the actual number in `i`.

```
for(i = 2; i<100; i++)
```

Then, for every number `i`, the code is looping again over all integers from `2` to `(i/j)`.

```
for(j = 2; j <= (i/j); j++)
```

Your loop's finishing condition is mathematically equivalent to `j` being smaller than the square root of `i`, since any larger integer `j` would already contain itself a smaller factor of `i`.
*(To check this, get a paper and rewrite the inequality so hat `i` is the sole part of the right hand side of your condition.)*

Then it checks whether or not `j` divides `i`.

```
(i%j)
```

If `j` is a factor of `i`, then `i` modulo `j` is zero and hence

```
if (!(i%j))
```

evaluates to `true` (since `0` is evualted as `false` and `!` negotiates this) and you can break out of the loop since `i` has a divisor not being `1` or `i`, hence `i` is not a prime.

On the other hand, if the inner loop is finished, you have found a prime since it has only `1` and `i` as divisor.

Needles to say that this bruteforce approach is very slow for large integers (you won't crack RSA with that), but does this clarify your questions?

Comment: i got it thank u :)

Answer (score 1):

1.`#include <stdio.h>` is a **header** that **defines three variable types, several macros, and various functions** for performing input and output. In other words, it's basically a C-Library being referenced to add some other externally defined logic, besides the code below, like the **size_t** variable, which is the result of the **sizeof** keyword for example. *That's just one example of what the the stdio.h header does* but you can see more info here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/stdio_h.htm

2.`int main()` is an **integer function** (`int`) that uses a deprecated declaration style `main()`, meaning you shouldn't it anymore because it's outdated by other functions, and the `main()` function in particular is a function that takes an **unspecified number of arguments** (*integers in this case*) and then runs some operations with those integers.

3. Next, the **curly braces** are what contain all the logic inside of the `int main()` function.  Then inside of it, on the line `int i, j;` , two local variables are declared (`i` and `j`) to be later used as placeholders for some **integers** that will be plugged into the function.
4. Below that, `for(i = 2; i<100; i++)` indicates there is a loop that sets the `i` variable to **2**, then after the semi-colon `i<100` means that the loop will continue to execute again and again as long as the variable *i* is **less than 100**. After yet another semi-colon, `i++` means that each time that the loop runs, the variable *i* will **increment by 1**. So it starts at 2, then 3, then 4, etc, **until `i` reaches 100** and the **loop stops executing**.
5. Next, `for(j = 2; j <= (i/j); j++)` is another loop inside of the first loop, but this time the loop is using the variable `j` as a placeholder/counter instead of the variable `i` (the variable used by the previous loop), which surrounds this loop starting with "`for(j...`" . This loop also sets`j` to **2** (*the same way the surrounding loop set `i` to 2)*; as long as `j` is **less than or equal to** (`i` **divided by** `j`) the loop will continue to execute; and `j` will **increment (increase) by one** each time that the loop is run, the same way that `i` does in the loop that surrounds this one.
6. `if(!(i%j)) break; // if factor found, not prime` this line means that the loop will **also stop** executing (`break`) if the remainder of `i` divided by `j` **does not equal zero.**
7. `if(j > (i/j)) printf("%d is prime", i);` This line means that if `j` is greater than `i` **divided by** `j` that the loop will write/**output the text** to stdout (*std out is the standard output device, a pointer to a FILE stream that represents the default output device for the application*).
8. Lastly, the last `return 0;` line indicates a **return from the function** and the **final curly brace** encloses the functions logic/code. The `main function` also **should return 0(also EXIT_SUCCESS)** to identify that the program has executed successfully and **-1 otherwise (also EXIT_FAILURE)**.

**Additional Note - Loops in every programming language I've seen personally tend to have a few things in common:**

i. **An init counter**, a value where the loop will initialize (start counting), inside the loop's parentheses and before the first semi-colon.

ii. **A test counter**, which will be evaluated each time that the loop continues, and if it evaluates to TRUE the loop will continue usually but if it evaluates to false then the loop will end. This is the part of the loop after the first semi-colon but before the second semi-colon.

iii. **An increment/decrement counter**, which increases or decreases the loop by some value each time that the loop is run. This is the part of the loop inside the parentheses, after the second semi-colon. If there is no increment counter or test counter that causes the loop to exit/break at some point, then this is known as an infinite loop. This is a very bad thing in programming because it will cause just about any computer program to crash since it will execute and consume computing resources indefinitely. Not good :)

**Disclaimer:** I don't actually code in C but the language has so many similarities with programming languages I do use, that I'm guessing this answer is very close if not 100% correct. Curious to hear some input from an expert C programmer though!

Comment: Your second point isn't correct. `main()` doesn't handle any arguments. What you mean is `main(int argc, char *argv[])`, which indeed should be handled carefully. Moreover, you need to use main() as entry point of your executable. It won't do anything otherwise.

Comment: @EduardI. Thanks! I really don't know the C programming language so it definitely helps to have someone correct me here! First time just now really that I ever actually looked at C lang documentation haha :)

Comment: You're welcome! Have a look at the [C reference for main](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function). I'm sure it will help you to enhance your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    /* local variable definition */
    int i, j;

    // Loop from 2 to 99; i will hold the number we are checking to
    // see if it is prime
    for(i = 2; i<100; i++) {
        // now loop through the numbers checking each one to see if
        // it is a factor of i (if it is, then i isn't prime).  This
        // loop stops when j^2 is greater than or equal to the number
        // we are checking
        for(j = 2; j <= (i/j); j++) {
            // i % j (i modulus j) is 0 iff j is a factor of i.  This
            // if test relies on the fact that 0 is false in C (and 
            // all nonzero values are true)
            if(!(i%j)) break; // if factor found, not prime
        }
        // this tests to see if we exited the above loop by failing
        // the test in the for() statement, or whether we exited the
        // loop via the break statement.  If we made it through all
        // iterations of the loop, then we found no factors, and the
        // number is prime.
        // 
        // note that a \n is missing at the end of the printf format
        // string.  The output will be "2 is prime3 is prime5..."
        if(j > (i/j)) printf("%d is prime", i);
    }

    // returns from main() with a value of 0, which will result in
    // the program exiting with an exit code of 0.  An explicit 
    // exit(0) is better form here, but this is not incorrect.
    return 0;
}
```